# JQuery Scroll-To Tabs to Remove UL Bullets

Tags: css

I have implemented from the JQuery SerialScroll Example and Im having some minor problems:

Here is the Fiddle which functions normal: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/nJu5D/

When I run this from my page in the browser Im having some issues.

From the SerialScrollTabs Class:

```
<div class="SerialScrollTabs">
   <ul class="navigations">
      <li><a href="#" id="btnOptions" tabindex="1" class="blue">Options </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="btnAvatar" tabindex="2" class="blue">Avatar </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="btnAbout" tabindex="3" class="blue">Tourism </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="btnSpecials" tabindex="4" class="blue">Specialties </a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

There are mysterious Bullet Points appearing in the Buttons.  Where are they coming from?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that navigations has a list-style-type of none in your CSS:

```
#navigations{list-style-type:none}
```

Comment: To add to that, jsFiddle automatically normalizes that style and removes the bullets, so that's why it works there.